# OpenLiberty JCA resource adapter and shared librabries - how?

Tags: jca, open-liberty

Is it possible to deploy a JCA resource adapter (rar) that references a shared library, inside the OpenLiberty server? What is the server.xml configuration snippet for this? I looked at the JCA docs for Liberty and found nothing on the topic...
My guess is something like this, but not sure:

```
<library id="mySharedLib">
        <fileset dir="${server.config.dir}/odb" includes="*.jar" />
</library>
...
<resourceAdapter id="myrar" location="${server.config.dir}/jca/my.rar">
        <properties.myrar conf="${server.output.dir}/jca/odb-server.xml"/>
        <classloader commonLibraryRef="mySharedLib"/>
</resourceAdapter>
```

Comment: I'm assuming since you accepted Mark's answer you tried the solution, but in case you didn't, I ran a quick test on lastest OL and the solution works as expected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's link to the schema for [resourceAdapter](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEQTP_liberty/com.ibm.websphere.liberty.autogen.nd.doc/ae/rwlp_config_resourceAdapter.html#classloader) which shows you can use classloader with a commonLibraryRef as you described. Something like the following:

```
<library id="MyLib">
    <fileset dir="/some/dir" includes="sharedlib.jar"/>
</library>

<resourceAdapter id="AdapterForMe" location="${server.config.dir}/connectors/RA.rar">
    <classloader commonLibraryRef="MyLib"/>
</resourceAdapter>
```